# FCM Web Push Message: Show Notification only when Website is closed (not in background)

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging

My serviceworker looks as follows:

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.1/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.0/firebase-messaging.js");

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: '%GCM_NOTIFICATION_APIKEY%',
    authDomain: '%GCM_NOTIFICATION_AUTHDOMAIN%',
    projectId: '%GCM_NOTIFICATION_PROJECTID%',
    storageBucket: '%GCM_NOTIFICATION_STORAGEBUCKET%',
    messagingSenderId: '%GCM_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGINGSENDERID%',
    appId: '%GCM_NOTIFICATION_APPID%',
    measurementId: '%GCM_NOTIFICATION_MEASUREMENTID%'
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
    
});
```

With the serviceworker you've see above iam getting a Notification when my tab/browser is in background.
Is it possible to get a notification **only** when the Website is closed?

Why at all iam getting a notification from the browser? The onBackgroundMessage callback is empty. Iam not calling showNotification()...

Thank you for your help!